# Инструменты миграций используемые с GO

Tags: база-данных, golang, devops

В мире Java чаще всего встречался Liquibase или Flyway, но изучая вопрос какие библиотеки/инструменты используют наткнулся на:

```
 - github.com/golang-migrate/migrate
 - github.com/pressly/goose
```

Изучив документацию двух библиотек, мне стало понятно как допустим добавить новую таблицу, или новый столбец, и при этом же сделать откат миграции, но если мне необходимо в миграции заполнить данными таблицу, или наоборот удалить какую то запись, и тут концепция "Up-Down" в моей голове не укладывается.

Так же не понятно как быть с деплоем, это должен быть отдельный скрипт на выполнение миграции?

**Хотелось бы прояснить для себя**:

- Что в себе должен содержать откат миграции, если в ней содержится только заполнение существующих таблиц?
- Есть ли какие то "хорошие практики" при работе с миграциями в "продуктовой" разработке?
- Как запускать миграцию при деплое?

Comment: Процесс миграций не затрагивает (и не должен затрагивать) изменения в самих данных, а только структуры таблиц и их связи. Для изменения данных необходимо создавать процесс отдельно от миграций, так как данные меняются, и при откате туда-обратно могут быть другими. Чтобы заполнить данными таблицы с нуля используют засеивания (Seed), а для изменения - конкретные SQL запросы.

Comment: у меня миграция накатывается сразу при запуске приложения. а SQL зашит в код через embed

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о такой библиотеке